# How can I add and use nvm in a DDEV web container?

Tags: ddev

Currently, the DDEV web container does not come with nvm (node version manager). How can I add and use it via the DDEV config.yaml file?

Comment: See the answer below; since DDEV v1.19.0, nvm has preinstalled with DDEV.

Answer (score 13):

In current ddev v1.19+ nvm is installed by default, and can be used with `ddev nvm`, so you don't have to do any of this. See [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/basics/cli-usage/#nodejs-npm-nvm-and-yarn). So do `ddev nvm install 12` for example. If you want to bake this into the config.yaml you might want to add something like this:

```yaml
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec: nvm install 12
  - exec: cd somepath && npm install
```

---- Original answer below ------

I recommend using the .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile approach, as it doesn't cost you every time you do a `ddev start`; it just builds one time in each project (and when you upgrade ddev).

Place this file in .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE

ENV NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=v6.10.1

RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR && bash install_nvm.sh
RUN echo "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" >>/etc/profile
RUN bash -ic "nvm install $NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION && nvm use $NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION"
RUN chmod -R ugo+w $NVM_DIR
```

Change NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to what you'd like it to be. You can add to this to use all the features of nvm; you could install more than one version, and use `nvm use <otherversion>` in a post-start hook if you wanted to.

For more about how to use and install nvm, see the [README](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md).

For more about how to use ddev's add-on Dockerfile capability, see [ddev docs on add-on Dockerfile](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage)

For details about Dockerfile syntax, see [Docker's Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

nvm is actually shell aliases, so it isn't available in the container to non-interactive commands by default. So it works fine inside `ddev ssh` but doesn't work out of the box in a post-start hook. To use it in a post-start hook you can do something like this:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: 'bash -l -c "nvm install v12.15.0 && nvm use v12.15.0"'
```

Comment: What I don't get yet: why does `ddev ssh; nvm ls;` does as expected, while the "direct call" with `ddev exec nvm ls` returns an error: `bash: nvm: command not found`?

Comment: `ddev exec` just runs bash, without any context, it doesn't load anything else. nvm is kind of a bash alias setup, it's dependent on getting loaded into your shell environment, so in this case is dependent on /etc/profile being run.

Comment: NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION is a better name for the environment variable (although it doesn't change the functionality). I changed it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Regarding the ddev exec point: should we then simply ssh into the container to run such things (actually, I have the same issue for foundation watch, be it via a web command or ddev exec)? Or should I keep trying?

Comment: I prefer `ddev ssh` because it's faster and smoother when you're doing more than one thing in the container. The reason there's a difference here is that nvm is pretty much integrated into the shell as an alias or something. I'm no expert on nvm; there may be other ways.

Comment: Great! I kind of thought I HAD to make sure commands could be executed from outside. Good to hear it‘s also fine to just ssh in. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With the help of @greggles and @heddn on the #ddev Slack channel (on the Drupal Slack workspace), I got it working with the following post-start hook:

```
hooks:
 post-start:
   - exec: curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
   - exec: rm -f ../.nvmrc && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && source "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install 8.11.1 && nvm use 8.11.1
```

This installs nvm then sets node to version 8.11.1

-mike

Comment: I added a Dockerfile answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61934500/215713) which doesn't end up costing so much time on every `ddev start`.

Comment: I suggest using a dedicated docker build file, instead of using post-start. This hook is executed every time you boot up your environment. A modification of the container will only be executed again when you destroy the container.

Answer (score 3):

After using @rfay solution above for installing specific version of Node, I created a custom command in **.ddev/commands/web** which allows me to run any nvm command in the container without having to **ddev ssh**.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Description: Install or use node.
## Usage: nvm [flags] [args]
## Example: "nvm use or nvm install"
source /etc/profile && nvm $@
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It throws `nvm` command not found error.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution would be to add it to the `.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile` as the DDEV documentation suggests here: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage

Comment: Dockerfile needs to be capitalized... Could you please add the full details as in Mike's example?